# </br> tag not working in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Not sure if this is a MVC or Razor problem. But I can't put a line break in my view. This is the code on the index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Vacant", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <!--TITLE-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--DESCRIPTION-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />   ----> HERE
        <!--TABS-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
```

As you can see I put the line break tag before to displayed the third field (Project) in my View.

The View is displayed without any error. However, the line break is not rendered between the 2nd and 3rd fields. Causing those two fields one after another with any space on them.

This is the screenshot

[image: Screenshot line break]

How could I put a line break between those two fields? Is there any @Html helper or Razor code to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: If the class `form-group` has a display of `inline-block`, then you are seeing a line break. The tab control is on the next line. If you add two line breaks, you would see space then.

Comment: it may not an issue with razor or mvc, after all it is just HTML once it is rendered on the browser. I tried a small test, <br/> tags are working. If you have any css associated with that class, you can check those things

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I checked that class and it doesn't contain the inline-block

Comment: Please don't use `<br>` , especially in this case. If you need extra space there, use a margin : either the `margin-top` of your bottom block, either the `margin-bottom` of the top block. You might want to add and use an extra class  on whatever block you choose so that your changes won't impact all the divs

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<div style="clear:both;margin-bottom:20px">

<!--TABS-->
<div class="form-group">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can insert one more Div Between them.
OR
You can decorate the TAB Div with some STYLE like-

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px">
```

OR
You can insert one more `<P />` Between them.